# Repository pattern for non SQL data sources

Tags: c#, repository-pattern

I want to create an N-Tier application consisting of business layer and a repository layer that handles a data source other than SQL databases, for example, if I want to implement a repository to read data from a text file or XML file and query the number of lines containing 'C#' or calculate average score etc

It seems that if the user invokes a call from the UI each time they want to query the data in the text file it would not be efficient for large files because it would make a call through the layers to the repository each time and need to load all of the data into memory and then query each time before returining it to display to the user - is there a way of loading all of the data once and then allowing more than one query to be performed on it or must it be loaded into memory each time before being queried?

Is there any efficient way of having an N-Tier design for non SQL database data sources without having to load the large amount of data/text file into memory each time?

Comment: Sounds like you just need to implement caching in your repositories. Like, read the data from the text file, store it in a variable (i.e., in memory), then read from that if present. You'd likely want to have some way of updating the variable if you know that the file has changed. But frankly, this question is a bit broad; there are innumerable ways to implement an n-tier design in the manner you're asking about.

Comment: Use Cache (MemoryCache in .Net 4.0 onwards) and refresh the Cache through a background process. And your query will run off of the Memory Cache.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan and loneshark thank you for your comments. It does sound like I need to cache the data returned from the text file. Would I need to load the entire contents of the text file into a cacheable object/property in the repository class? How does it get stored and re-used over multiple transactions, I don't understand.

Comment: @loneshark99 I have used MemoryCache as per your suggestion. If you add it as an answer I can mark it as the answer. Thanks.

Comment: @Theomax  Ok, glad it helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use memory cache from .net and then have a background process update the cache periodically. Your queries will run off of the cache .

Thanks.